# How apply SQL LIMIT for a three structure data?

Tags: mysql, sql, tree, binary-tree

I use a famous method for showing the three comment from SQL.
How I can display only first three root comment with a all sub-comment?

I tried to make something like:

```
  SELECT * FROM NAMES  ORDER BY pid LIMIT 3 ASC, Id ASC LIMIT 3
```

But **LIMIT** is not supported SQL for each **ORDER BY**

The example you can see here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a593d/4

More clear I illustrated in [loaded image](http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g4b92f3dfa275b84d99956811460c126eb34bc6d10)

Comment: what is your desired result from sqlfiddle data ?

Comment: I need get last sorted 3 parent (PID = 0) with a all them childs

Comment: Still not clear, please add desired result in your question

Comment: I attached a image file at question. Click to download. There is a scheme of MYsql result, that I need. The limit might be not only 3, also any number. I want to reduce the load on the database as well as to not display a lot of comments in the page. The rest will be loaded via Ajax, so I need LIMIT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM NAMES INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT pid 
      FROM NAMES
      GROUP BY pid
      ORDER BY pid
      LIMIT 3) AS my_table 
  USING (pid)
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a593d/15)**

Comment: @Arsen, is this what you need ?

Comment: **GROUP BY pid** not need, I need all PID's with first three ID. Or correctly tell such: I need get first ID with all PID.

Comment: I am not sure, will give me this query data sorted how as: `ORDER BY pid LIMIT 3 ASC, Id ASC`?  Can not chech, Sql online informed that does not support subquery

Comment: It looks a good solution, works! Thank you! Is it not slow query? I  have known about `USING`

Comment: So, if I want select last 3 and after next 3 rows- I need use `LIMIT 0,2, LIMIT 3, 6`?

Comment: No it won't be that slow, it depends on amount of data you have in db.

Comment: To fetch next three you can use LIMIT 3, 6... here 3 is the offset and 6 is limit which means it will skip three rows

Answer (score 1):

The LIMIT keyword in SQL limits the amount of rows that is returned. It there is a sort involved SQL will be smart enough to stop the ordering after the first three rows are found.

If you want to do something else with the LIMIT keyword then you should explain what exactly it is you want to get.

Comment: I know about it...I need limit the number of parent rows with all childs rows.

Comment: Look please attach image in question